# Sequential Duplicates in a Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can anyone help me with either a single cell formula or VBA to find the duplicates in consecutive cells in a row with

1. Two consecutive cells having the same value = 1,
2. Three consecutive cells having the same value = 2
3. ... so on ....

I have a set of data with around 500 rows with data for 31 days (Success or Failure), I need to find how many times there is a failure consecutively for 2 days and further since a days failure and success next day is acceptable.

Hope am clear enough.... Remember I cannot insert rows in between lines to use `countif` (Data cannot be touched) So I need to output on the 32nd column.

This is urgent as well for me

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: Without further describing your data we can't help. Also, you haven't said what you have tried, showing to us a lack of effort. If it is urgent then just eyeball the data. Perhaps using a conditional formatting to to "hide" failures would help with the eyeball method.

Comment: Please share some sample data and the expected output, help us to fix the issue!!

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem? You can upload a screenshot or sample file.

Comment: Can someone guide me how to upload the file in here

Answer (score 1):

First enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function consecu(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim arr(1 To 31) As Long, i As Long
    Dim r As Range
    arr(1) = 0
    i = 1

    For Each r In rng
        If i = 1 Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            If r.Value = r.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                arr(i) = arr(i - 1) + 1
            Else
                arr(i) = 0
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r

    consecu = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr)
End Function
```

Then with data from **A1** through **AE1**, in **AF1** enter:

```
=consecu(A1:AE1)
```

For example:

[image]